# Appending line points with same slope to Python dict

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function where I can spit out all the points in the same line. I am calculating that by the fact, that the slope between two pairs of points must be same for that.

I have iterated through input file to get a list of points and calculated slope. My next step would be to put them on a HashMap (or Dict in Python), with the key being the slope and update it with points and slope. If slope for those two numbers is already present, add the points to same entry and remove any duplicates.

I was able to extract input, calculate slope and put them on in a hashmap. However, putting them on hashmap is a bit challenging for me as I am trying to use Java-like syntax which I am familiar with.

Can someone help me with updating the hashmap ensuring no dups are inserted?

here is what I have done so far:

```
slopeMap = {}    
for x in range (0, len(arr)):
    for y in range (x+1, len(arr)):
        slopeForPoints =  (slope(arr[x][0], arr[y][0], arr[x][1], arr[y][1]))
        if slopeMap.has_key(slopeForPoints) == False:
            slopeMap[slopeForPoints].append()


        "slopeForPoints" in slopeMap
            slopeMap["slopeForPoints"] = 
        a.setdefault("somekey",[]).append("bob")

        print slopeForPoints
```

I just need help with the above function. Slope and iterate function I was able to get working.

Sample slope values (Key- HashMap)

```
0.0
1.0
0.0
0.9
```

Sample point values (Value - HashMap)

```
0.0,0.0
1.1,1.1
3.5,4.5
2.2,2.2
```

Comment: Why don't you calculate the slope and the intercept, which will be truly unique for any line and use that instead of doing filtering or cleaning up or whatever?

Comment: I have list of points only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Mad Physicist, you need to calculate the more than just the slope to identify unique lines, as parallel lines would have the same slope but not necessarily be the same line.

There are a few options for this. One such option is to make the keys of your dictionary tuples, such as `(slope, intercept)`. Then to make sure the points are unique, you could make the values for your dictionary sets of tuples.

The idea would look something like this:

```
slope, intercept = slope_intercept(point1, point2) #Each point is (point_x, point_y)
                                                   #Need to write the slope_intercept function
if (slope, intercept) not in slopeMap:
    slopeMap[(slope,intercept)] = set() #Could be done with a defaultDict instead
slopeMap[(slope,intercept)].add(point1))
slopeMap[(slope,intercept)].add(point2))
```

---

Note, it's more Pythonic to say

```
if slopeForPoints not in slopeMap:
```

Comment: Tried this one with the implementation. The output of intercept is float. Now when I try to use slope, intercept = slope_intercept(point1, point2) #Each point is (point_x, point_y) I get TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Any idea for the same. slope function also returns float value